# Uploaded file can not be opened when clicking the link

Tags: php, laravel, file

```
                                 {{ trans('cruds.ticket.fields.attachments') }}
                            
                            <td>
                                @foreach($ticket->attachments as $attachment)
                               <a href="{{ $attachment->getUrl() }}">{{ $attachment->file_name }}</a>
                                @endforeach
                            </td>
```

It is displaying error like this when I click on the link...

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.5

Comment: Hi, perhaps print the link? You might need to configure Apache to serve the files in that directory or have a file download script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

laravel framework have nice storage mechanism.

And by seeing you code, i assuming that,
the `$attachment->getUrl()` should be return something like: `localhost/abc.img` and it doesn't match with any resource managed by apache server.

so. let change the link that `$attachment->getUrl()` return to `localhost/files/abc.img`
and create a routes for this link like:

```php
Route::get('files/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    $file = Storage::get('files/'.$filename);
    $type = $mimetype = Storage::mimeType('product_image/'.$filename);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```